# Guage/Speedometer Charts Using Donut

Tags: donut-chart, image-charts

Is there a way to emulate in image-charts the old Google Guage chart in a manner similar to how chart.js creates a donut with only a portion of the donut's circumference, thickness, etc?

(video on how to do it in chart.js https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzktiZUdzIE)